# Google Assistant Voice Actions are working fine in Android 10 but shows toast `App not installed` in above android 10 devices

Tags: android, plugins, action, voice, assistant

Google Assistant Voice Actions are working fine in Android 10 but shows toast `App not installed` in above android 10 devices.

I tried all possible solutions mentioned over SOF.